# How to see the full path of where a module is being imported from when it's not found?

Tags: python, import, path

I'm importing a local .py file:

```
from mymodule.utilities import DateUpdate
```

and I'm getting an ImportError:

> ```
> ImportError: No module named mymodule.utilities
> ```

The issue is probably just that I'm making it look in the wrong spot, but it'd be nice to have an actual log as to know where it tried to look. Something like:

> ```
> ImportError: No module named mymodule.utilities
> We looked in: /user/Desktop/myproject/extra/mymodule/utilities
> ```

Like that, I would at least know where it's looking and try to fix it with some kind of feedback from the console.

Comment: The paths you are looking are in ``sys.path``.  You can print that out to see.  ``import sys; print(sys.path)``, or format it to make it more readable as it's just an array.

Comment: But how does that print where it's trying to take mymodule.utilities from? I'm not sure I get it.

Comment: All the values in ``sys.path`` ARE the places that it looks for ``mymodule.utilities``.  So for each directory in ``sys.path`` you need to see if ``mymodule/`` is in it.